# Problems getting database data from id in link

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I've currently got this code, where my goal is to fetch the data from a array in the database (oppdrID) corresponding to the id in the URL (blabla.php?id=8). Right now when I run this code nothing shows up, no errors no nothing.

// Updated code. Error message "( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in C:\wamp64\www\prosjekt\endre.php on line 39"

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stilsett.php' />
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Endre oppdrag // Prosjekt - PHP</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
include "funksjoner.inc.php";
echo "<div id='header'>";

echo navigasjon();

echo "</div>";

echo "<div id='innhold'>";

$db = kobleTil();

if (isset($_GET['oppdrID']) && is_numeric($_GET['oppdrID']) &&       $_GET['oppdrID'] > 0) {

$id = $_GET['oppdrID'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM oppdrag WHERE oppdrID = ?";

$stmt = $db->stmt_init();
if ($stmt->prepare($sql))
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();

while ($nesteRad = $stmt->get_result()){

echo "<hr />";

    echo "<table id='resultat'>";
    echo "<tr><th>Navn</th><th>Type</th><th>Startdato</th><th>Sluttdato</th>  <th>Antall timer</th><th>Aktiv</th></tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $nesteRad['navn'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $nesteRad['type'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $nesteRad['startDato'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $nesteRad['sluttDato'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $nesteRad['timer'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $nesteRad['aktiv'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr></table>";

    $stmt->close();


    echo "<hr />";

    }
}

echo    "<form action='kjoer2.php' method='post'>";
echo    "<table id='leggInn'><tr><td>
    <label for='startTid'>Starttid</label></td><td><input type='datetime-  local' name='startTid' id='skjemaLeggInn'></td></tr>
    <tr><td>
    <label for='slutTid'>Sluttid</label></td><td><input type='datetime-  local' name='slutTid' id='skjemaLeggInn'></td></tr>
    <tr><td>
    <label for='merknad'>Merknad</label></td><td><textarea name='merknad'   rows='10' cols='30'  id='skjemaLeggInn'></textarea></td></tr>
    <tr><td>
    <label for='antTimer'>Antall Timer</label></td><td><input type='text'    name='antTimer' id='skjemaLeggInn'>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type='submit' value='Legg inn'>
    </td></tr>
    </form>";

echo "</div>";
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: oppdrID this parameter isn't available in URL ? then why you are checking its existence .

Comment: oh ... changed all to ['id'], still nada

Comment: what does these `kobleTil()` `navigasjon()` functions do? or is it irrelevant?

Comment: You're also outputting before header. You say *"no errors no nothing"* that's because you're not checking for errors via php's error reporting and on the query and you do have errors.

Comment: the kobleTil() connects the thing to the database.

Comment: and navigasjon() is just a navigation

Answer (score 0):

Your URL should be something like `blabla.php?oppdrID=8`

Then fix your code to get the right param, and add it to your SQL:

```
$id = $_GET['oppdrID'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM oppdrag WHERE oppdrID = ?";

if ($statement = $db->prepare($sql)) {
    $statement->bind_param("i", $id);
    $statement->execute();
...
```